# Disable Input Fields

Tags: html

I would like to disable 2 time input types, if the value of other input types is the same which is the date data types.

```
<tr>
           <td>Date From</td>
           <td><input type="date" name="DateFrom" style="width: 235px" required></td>
           //Example: the inputted value is 08/23/2016
</tr>
<tr>
           <td>Date To</td>
           <td><input type="date" name="DateTo" style="width: 235px" required></td>
           //Example: the user will also input 08/23/2016
</tr>
<tr>
           <td>Time From</td>
           <td><input type="time" name="TimeFrom" style="width: 235px" ></td>
           //This input field will be disabled
</tr>
<tr>
           <td>Time To</td>
           <td><input type="time" name="TimeTo" style="width: 235px" ></td>
           //This input field will be disabled
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following jQuery function it will compare the values of both the date fields whenever they change , if both fields have same value it will disable the time fields else enable them

```
function compare() {
    var FromDate = $("[name='DateFrom']").val()
    var ToDate = $("[name='DateTo']").val()
    if (FromDate === ToDate) {
        $("[name='TimeTo']").prop('disabled', true)
        $("[name='TimeFrom']").prop('disabled', true)
    } else {
        $("[name='TimeTo']").prop('disabled', false)
        $("[name='TimeFrom']").prop('disabled', false)
    }
}
$("[name='DateFrom']").on("change", function() {
    change();
});
$("[name='DateTo']").on("change", function() {
    compare();
});
```

check out the link http://jsbin.com/zitezol/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How to call the javascript file?

Comment: use following script tag in <head> section of your page and change source attribute to link your own javascript file .
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js"></script>

Comment: and don't forget to add jquery reference in your <head> tag before you call your own javascript file use the following
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand what you want to do, but I think this is similar to what you want:

```
<script>
    var dateFrom = document.getElementsByName('DateFrom')[0]; /* get the DateFrom element */

    var dateTo = document.getElementsByName('DateTo')[0]; /* get the DateTo element*/

    /* check if their the same date */
    if(dateFrom.value == dateTo.value){
        /* disable the time selectors */
        document.getElementsByName('TimeFrom')[0].disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByName('TimeTo')[0].disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```